# How do I indent n spaces in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I want to indent an entire region n spaces to the right or left. I can do this in some modes with C-c > and C-c <, but I'd like to do this in general.

If I need to change my *.emacs* file in order to make this efficient (with a keyboard shortcut like that above), that's fine.

Comment: What's with the close votes? How-do-I-do-foo questions for emacs have been on SO for ages, and some people's need to shuffle everything around doesn't change that.

Comment: Been [discussed on meta repeatedly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=emacs), too (albeit with little conclusions). The best of the lot is probably [Can we please have a ruling about Emacs questions on SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79659/2509) where the leading answer concludes that they belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit frustrating, but I'm dubious we're going to see any policy about this. The recommendation I saw was that, because there's no clear single site where they all belong (and the idea of an Emacs-specific SE site was apparently rejected), they should generally just be left where the original user put them.

Answer (score 32):

What works for me is: select a region and then *C-u <number of spaces> C-x TAB*

[Re Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918134/how-do-i-indent-n-spaces-in-emacs#comment30482284_11830118), we could define a function and bind to a keyboard shortcut, e.g., *C-x C-TAB*. Try adding this to your Emacs configuration.

```
(defun insert-tabs (n)
  "Inserts N number of tabs"
  (interactive "nNumber of tabs: ")
  (dotimes (i n)
    (indent-for-tab-command)))

(global-set-key [?\C-x \C-tab] 'insert-tabs)
```

Comment: This works great, but I can't remember it. Any hints? (Other than bookmarking this page.)

Comment: @EricWilson Hi Eric, I updated the answer with another suggestion.

Comment: Nice function, but what I'd really like would be a sementic clue to the commands being executed. Does `C-u` mean something by itself?

Comment: @EricWilson I see. Yes, `C-u` (`universal-argument`) when given an integer N repeats a command that follows it N times. Here's a link to the docs: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html

Answer (score 14):

The key part of [Sandro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918134/how-do-i-indent-n-spaces-in-emacs/6918574#6918574) is the call to `indent-rigidly`.

```
C-x TAB (translated from C-x <tab>) runs the command indent-rigidly,
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `indent.el'.

It is bound to C-x TAB.

(indent-rigidly start end arg)

Indent all lines starting in the region sideways by arg columns.
Called from a program, takes three arguments, start, end and arg.
You can remove all indentation from a region by giving a large negative arg.
```

So, mark the region, enter a numeric argument, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Answer (score 11):

I think that the following piece of code can help you:

```
;; Shift the selected region right if distance is positive, left if
;; negative

(defun shift-region (distance)
  (let ((mark (mark)))
    (save-excursion
      (indent-rigidly (region-beginning) (region-end) distance)
      (push-mark mark t t)
      ;; Tell the command loop not to deactivate the mark
      ;; for transient mark mode
      (setq deactivate-mark nil))))

(defun shift-right ()
  (interactive)
  (shift-region 1))

(defun shift-left ()
  (interactive)
  (shift-region -1))

;; Bind (shift-right) and (shift-left) function to your favorite keys. I use
;; the following so that Ctrl-Shift-Right Arrow moves selected text one
;; column to the right, Ctrl-Shift-Left Arrow moves selected text one
;; column to the left:

(global-set-key [C-S-right] 'shift-right)
(global-set-key [C-S-left] 'shift-left)
```

You can replace the `(shift-region 1)` and the `(shift-region 1)` by the value you want.

As you can see, my function wraps indent-rigidly:

> indent-rigidly is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> `indent.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-x TAB.
>
> (indent-rigidly START END ARG)
>
> Indent all lines starting in the region sideways by ARG columns.
> Called from a program, takes three arguments, START, END and ARG. You
> can remove all indentation from a region by giving a large negative
> ARG.

Answer (score 9):

Also useful are the [rectangle commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html) that operate on rectangles of text instead of lines of text.

For example, after marking a rectangular region,

`C-x r o` inserts blank space to fill the rectangular region (effectively shifting code to the right)
`C-x r k` kills  the rectangular region (effectively shifting code to the left)

Answer (score 2):

You inform yourself about [Rectangles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RectangleCommands).

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer. Can you [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6918600/edit)? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

Use *[Cua-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode)*.

*M-x cua-mode* to activate, *C-RET* to select the first column of the whole region, and type space. Finally, <kbd>Esc</kbd> three times to escape, and done.