# Emacs -- debugging an overlay in conjunction with syntax skipping

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking for some assistance, please to debug my `test` function so that the **yellow** vertical line looks exactly the same as the **red** line.  I have decided to exclude highlighting **tabs** because they are two (2) characters wide and it makes the vertical line like distorted.  In my attempt to *exclude* `tabs`, however, I lose highlighting of any text to the immediate right.  My attempts at fixing this breaks the functionality of the **blue** and/or **red** lines.

In a nutshell, the **blue** and **red** lines are working as desired, but the **yellow** line is broken (to the immediate right of a tab) -- the **yellow** line should look just like the **red** line.

The problem with my `test` function lies in the following code snippet:

```lisp
(not (save-excursion (move-to-column my-col-b)
   (< 0 (skip-chars-forward "\t"))))

(not (save-excursion (move-to-column my-col-b)
    (> 0 (skip-chars-backward "\t")))))
```

---

The following functions were used to create the image of buffer depicted in the screenshot below:

```lisp
(defun test ()
(interactive)
  (let* (my-last-column
      my-o-beg-a my-o-end-a (my-col-a 3)
      my-o-beg-b my-o-end-b (my-col-b 28)
      my-o-beg-c my-o-end-c (my-col-c 29) )
    (generate-test-buffer)
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (while (re-search-backward "\n" (point-min) t)
      (setq my-last-column (current-column))
      (setq my-o-beg-a (progn (move-to-column my-col-a) (point)))
      (setq my-o-end-a (+ 1 my-o-beg-a))
      (setq my-o-beg-b (progn (move-to-column my-col-b) (point)))
      (setq my-o-end-b (+ 1 my-o-beg-b))
      (setq my-o-beg-c (progn (move-to-column my-col-c) (point)))
      (setq my-o-end-c (+ 1 my-o-beg-c))
      (when (and
          (< my-col-a my-last-column)
          (not (save-excursion (move-to-column my-col-a)
              (< 0 (skip-chars-forward "\t"))))
          (not (save-excursion (move-to-column my-col-a)
              (> 0 (skip-chars-backward "\t")))))
        (overlay-put (make-overlay my-o-beg-a my-o-end-a) 'face '(
          (background-color . "cyan")
          (foreground-color . "black") )))
      (when (and
          (< my-col-b my-last-column)
          (not (save-excursion (move-to-column my-col-b)
              (< 0 (skip-chars-forward "\t"))))
          (not (save-excursion (move-to-column my-col-b)
              (> 0 (skip-chars-backward "\t")))))
        (overlay-put (make-overlay my-o-beg-b my-o-end-b) 'face '(
          (background-color . "yellow")
          (foreground-color . "black") )))
      (when (and
          (< my-col-b my-last-column)
          (not (save-excursion (move-to-column my-col-c)
              (< 0 (skip-chars-forward "\t"))))
          (not (save-excursion (move-to-column my-col-c)
              (> 0 (skip-chars-backward "\t")))))
        (overlay-put (make-overlay my-o-beg-c my-o-end-c) 'face '(
          (background-color . "red")
          (foreground-color . "black") ))) )))

(defun generate-test-buffer ()
  (if (get-buffer "foo.el")
    (with-current-buffer "foo.el"
      (erase-buffer))
    (get-buffer-create "foo.el"))
  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer "foo.el"))
  (setq whitespace-style '(face space-mark tab-mark newline-mark) )
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
  (setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 4 200 4))
  (setq tab-width 4)
  (setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
  (whitespace-mode t)
  (insert ";;;;")
  (insert-tabs 1)
  (insert "(defun test ()\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 1)
  (insert "(interactive)\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 2)
  (insert "(let* (my-last-column\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 4)
  (insert "my-o-beg-a my-o-end-a (my-col-a 1)\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 4)
  (insert "my-o-beg-b my-o-end-b (my-col-b 11)\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 4)
  (insert "my-o-beg-c my-o-end-c (my-col-c 16) )\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 3)
  (insert "(generate-test-buffer)\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 3)
  (insert "(goto-char (point-max))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 3)
  (insert "(while (re-search-backward \"\\n\" (point-min) t)\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 4)
  (insert "(setq my-last-column (current-column))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 4)
  (insert "(setq my-o-beg-a (progn (move-to-column my-col-a) (point)))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 4)
  (insert "(setq my-o-end-a (+ 1 my-o-beg-a))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 4)
  (insert "(setq my-o-beg-b (progn (move-to-column my-col-b) (point)))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 4)
  (insert "(setq my-o-end-b (+ 1 my-o-beg-b))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 4)
  (insert "(setq my-o-beg-c (progn (move-to-column my-col-c) (point)))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 4)
  (insert "(setq my-o-end-c (+ 1 my-o-beg-c))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 4)
  (insert "(when (and\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 6)
  (insert "(< my-col-a my-last-column)\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 6)
  (insert "(not (save-excursion (move-to-column my-col-a)\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 7)
  (insert "(< 0 (skip-chars-forward \"\t\"))))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 6)
  (insert "(not (save-excursion (move-to-column my-col-a)\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 7)
  (insert "(> 0 (skip-chars-backward \"\t\")))))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 5)
  (insert "(overlay-put (make-overlay my-o-beg-a my-o-end-a) 'face '(\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 6)
  (insert "(background-color . \"cyan\")\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 6)
  (insert "(foreground-color . \"black\") )))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 4)
  (insert "(when (and\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 6)
  (insert "(< my-col-b my-last-column)\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 7)
  (insert "(not (save-excursion (move-to-column my-col-b)\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 7)
  (insert "(< 0 (skip-chars-forward \"\t\"))))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 6)
  (insert "(not (save-excursion (move-to-column my-col-b)\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 7)
  (insert "(> 0 (skip-chars-backward \"\t\")))))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 5)
  (insert "(overlay-put (make-overlay my-o-beg-b my-o-end-b) 'face '(\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 6)
  (insert "(background-color . \"yellow\")\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 6)
  (insert "(foreground-color . \"black\") )))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 4)
  (insert "(when (and\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 6)
  (insert "(< my-col-b my-last-column)\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 6)
  (insert "(not (save-excursion (move-to-column my-col-c)\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 7)
  (insert "(< 0 (skip-chars-forward \"\t\"))))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 6)
  (insert "(not (save-excursion (move-to-column my-col-c)\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 7)
  (insert "(> 0 (skip-chars-backward \"\t\")))))\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 5)
  (insert "(overlay-put (make-overlay my-o-beg-c my-o-end-c) 'face '(\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 6)
  (insert "(background-color . \"red\")\n;;;;")
  (insert-tabs 6)
  (insert "(foreground-color . \"black\") ))) )))\n" ))

(defun insert-tabs (n)
;; http://stackoverflow.com/a/11830118/2112489
  "Inserts N number of tabs"
  (interactive "nNumber of tabs: ")
  (dotimes (i n)
    (indent-for-tab-command)))
```

---

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/test_05_03_2014_a.png))</sub>

Comment: I assume that you've already had a look at [**this**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightCurrentColumn) wiki page (and [`col-highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/col-highlight.el) in particular). What is it that you are trying to do that is different?

Comment: @Drew -- It's been several months since I tried all of the vertical highlighters on the Wiki page.  My recollection is that at least one of them inserted what looked to be whitespace, perhaps a conflict with whitespace-mode.  None of them created a straight line that was vertical -- there was always some discrepancy where some was to the left or to the right -- i.e., a jagged edged ruler.  My recollection was that none of them could go beyond the end of a line, so there was never a true ruler from top to bottom of the buffer if the point on the current line was beyond a shorter line.

Comment: @Drew -- With my recent modification of the Fill Column Indicator ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/23418459/2112489 ), I can achieve a straight vertical line and have a line spanning the vertical length of the buffer even if other lines are shorter than the current line.  The lesson I learned from @phils this morning (i.e., `this-command`) will enable me to precisely control when the vertical line is redrawn.

Comment: @Drew -- In the context of this current thread, I'm looking to highlight characters that are immediately to the right of a tab -- without highlighting the tab and without breaking the functionality of character highlighting to the left of a tab.

Comment: Maybe the problem is just that `move-to-column` moves past a TAB char entirely: "If specified column is within a character, point goes after that character."  Dunno, just a thought.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you move backward past the TABs, so this test is true: `(> 0 (skip-chars-backward "\t"))`, so the `not` gives false, so the yellow overlay is never created in this case.

Comment: Removing that `(not (save-excursion...))` seems to make the yellow line like the red one.

Comment: @Drew -- agreed.  However, removal of `(not (save-excursion (move-to-column my-col-b) (> 0 (skip-chars-backward "\t"))))`, breaks the ability to test for a tab in the void -- i.e., no character to the immediate left or right of the tab.  Due to the fact that tabs have visually varying widths on screen, yet only equal to one (1) `point` in width, highlighting the tabs creates a visual distortion of the vertical line.  That is the reason I was hoping to not highlight any tabs -- there would be a break in the vertical line, but at least it would not look jagged.

Comment: @Drew -- Perhaps if we could do something like `(unless (or (equal (get-char (current-column)) "TAB") (equal (get-char (current-column)) nil)) . . . place an overlay at (current-column))` ?  A test for `nil` would be needed if a tab precedes a character, but the width displayed is larger than one character such that more than one column exists between `TAB` and the character immediately to the right.

Comment: I think I'm on the right track now . . . `(string (preceding-char))`; `(string (char-after (point)))`; `(string (following-char))`

Comment: @Drew -- I found a working solution `(not (progn (move-to-column (+ 1 my-col-b)) (eq (preceding-char) 9)))`.  Thank you for taking a look at this thread and for helping to troubleshoot this issue.  It was very difficult because the number of columns differs from the number of `points` when the `tab-width` is greater than one (1).

Comment: You're kind, but I didn't help much, if at all. Glad you were able to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**May 3, 2014**:  Initial answer -- apparent working solution.

- A tab has a character code of `9`.
- The width of a tab is equal to *only* one (1) `point`.
- A tab can be equal to one *or more* columns wide, depending upon the `tab-width`.
- When dealing with tabs, determining the type of character that follows a particular `column` is problematic because . . . [to be filled in when I understand more].
- When dealing with tabs, moving forward one (1) `point` and looking back is also problematic because . . . [to be filled in when I understand more].

The working solution is to move one (1) `column` ahead and check the *preceding* character code -- if it is still a character code of `9`, then do *not* place an overlay (at that preceding column).  If the target column was already on a non-tab character, then moving forward one (1) `column` and looking back should logically yield the proper result.

```lisp
(defun test ()
(interactive)
  (let* (my-last-column
      my-o-beg-a my-o-end-a (my-col-a 3)
      my-o-beg-b my-o-end-b (my-col-b 28)
      my-o-beg-c my-o-end-c (my-col-c 29) )
    (generate-test-buffer)
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (while (re-search-backward "\n" (point-min) t)
      (setq my-last-column (current-column))
      (setq my-o-beg-a (progn (move-to-column my-col-a) (point)))
      (setq my-o-end-a (+ 1 my-o-beg-a))
      (setq my-o-beg-b (progn (move-to-column my-col-b) (point)))
      (setq my-o-end-b (+ 1 my-o-beg-b))
      (setq my-o-beg-c (progn (move-to-column my-col-c) (point)))
      (setq my-o-end-c (+ 1 my-o-beg-c))
      (when (and
          (< my-col-a my-last-column)
          (not (progn (move-to-column (+ 1 my-col-a)) (eq (preceding-char) 9))))
        (overlay-put (make-overlay my-o-beg-a my-o-end-a) 'face '(
          (background-color . "cyan")
          (foreground-color . "black") )))
      (when (and
          (< my-col-b my-last-column)
          (not (progn (move-to-column (+ 1 my-col-b)) (eq (preceding-char) 9))))
        (overlay-put (make-overlay my-o-beg-b my-o-end-b) 'face '(
          (background-color . "yellow")
          (foreground-color . "black") )))
      (when (and
          (< my-col-b my-last-column)
          (not (progn (move-to-column (+ 1 my-col-c)) (eq (preceding-char) 9))))
        (overlay-put (make-overlay my-o-beg-c my-o-end-c) 'face '(
          (background-color . "red")
          (foreground-color . "black") ))) )))
```